# meaning of “born” in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is an excerpt from Ishmael Beah’s essay *A Long Way Gone*.

> When we were walking, I turned around to see the village one last time. It was ***yet to be born*** for that day. A cock crowed to dispatch the last remains of night and to mute the crickets that couldn’t let go of the darkness of their own accord.

In this context, what is the meaning of the word “born”?

Comment: Poetic phrasing, perhaps, for the new day that hadn’t quite arrived yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a metaphor for the way in which life in the village was yet to start for the day. Presumably all was quiet, no people were to be seen, no fires lit to make smoke, no noises heard. The cock crowed, and very soon the village would spring into life - would be born into the day’s activities.

Comment: You could probably find the broadened usage in a dictionary.